# Can I customise the columns on the 'Find Participants' page?

Tags: civievent, registration, custom-search, participants

I'd like to customise the columns on the 'Find Participants' page. I want to swap 'fee level' and 'amount' for 'employer' and 'job title'. Have I missed something obvious in Civi's customisation options? I feel like I've looked everywhere!

(We need to know this info to approve people for our events, and our current process is to export all in a spreadsheet, view the relevant info there, choose who gets approved, then load that info back into civicrm. It would be great if we could just do this all on one screen, without a separate spreadsheet.)

Details: Wordpress 4.9.8; Civicrm 5.4.0

Caveat: I'm not a (fluent/confident) coder or techie person...!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Its possible to alter the Columns in some search results of CiviCRM and definitely **YES** for participant search result.

You can create an extension and implement [hook_civicrm_searchColumns](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_searchColumns/) hook. You can also find an example how to use the hook in the [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_searchColumns/).

Other alternate would be to create a report with same filters as Participant search but you won't be able to perform any action like how you can on participant search eg Update Participant status, Delete participants etc.

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a profile with your desired fields and then do an advanced search to result the columns according to your profile. Eg.

- Navigate to `Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Profiles`. Add a profile with `Search Views` enabled.

  [image]
- Add your required fields to it.
- Navigate to Advanced Search and select this profile as a view of resulting columns.

[image]